# Stuck in memory leaks in my project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, memory-leaks, didreceivememorywarning

I am using UIImage picker, Local notification, event calendar, Date Picker , Facebook Sharing, Sounds, Navigation controller , database . My application is crash after some time, the reason is not same, Some times memory is full and some times too manny other receive memory warning. Please guide me how can i generally remove the leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [Cocoa Tutorial: Fixing Memory Leaks With Instruments](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/). Instruments is the way to go to find leaks.

More resources:

- [Finding iPhone Memory Leaks: A “Leaks” Tool Tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/)
- [Apple's official Memory Usage Performance Guidelines / Finding Memory Leaks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Intstruments with the Leaks profile... see this article [Leaks!](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

1.first of all release the objects in the dealloc .
2.Go to the xcode there in mainmenu you find the build tab.In that pressed on the build and analyze .It gives the errors.Remove those warnings.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `autorelease` objects, make sure it gets released at the right time. If you can,try not to use `Interface Builder`, i feel something is fishy abt it when it comes to memory.

Check the `NSString` objects, they can have devastating effects if not released on time.

also remember `[UIImage imageNamed@"abc.png"]` caches the images which also causes running low memory warnings.

Try to create your view hierarchy programmatically.